# Show only one item from the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, game-development

I have this little Pacman game made in JavaScript

Whats is happening is when i call a random item from the array this is what the game return:
**[Video here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1twCbGcRA83-bgvZxV5Q3316oulM8imlB/view?usp=sharing)**

The game show all the items from the array, before display only one of then...

A part of the code

```js
if (gameOver || gameWin) {
//display this array if game win
    text = textOptionsWin[Math.floor(Math.random() * textOptionsWin.length)];;
    if (gameOver) {
    //display this array if game over
      text = textOptions[Math.floor(Math.random() * textOptions.length)];;
      //go back to the first level if lost 
      setTimeout(function () {
        if (tileMap.fase == 1) {
          location.href = "/?fase=1";
          // text = "O COVID-19 TE PEGOU! ";
        } else if (tileMap.fase == 2) {
          location.href = "/?fase=1";
        } else if (tileMap.fase == 3) {
          location.href = "/?fase=1";
        } 
      }, 2500);
       //Delay to change the level
    }
}
```

I'm **missing** something to this happen? any tip can be useful

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand, but I think this is the answer:

```
var a = ["end1", "end2", "end3"]

console.log(a[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)])
```

This prints a random item in the array 'a' to console.

Comment: I tried as you said, but didn't work